# Instagram API Get max_tag_id

Tags: codeigniter

I am an Instagram developer. I am trying to search images using the API with the hashtag.

I got the total count of the images but when I am trying to view these images it required "min_tag_id" and "max_tag_id".

Please tell me, any API which provides these two values.

Answer (score 0):

*try this*
`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

Comment: This API returns a warning.   https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2867599/b6ceadbf6bd2c2e064ff6acdafa6d2c0

Answer (score 0):

You won't have any post for that tag. That's what it shows like that.Then visit (https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN). It will work